# firebase function error deploying a scheduled function listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var database = admin.database();
//var tarih = new Date();
var d = Date.now(); 

var userTimeZoneOffset = 3; 

var timeInRegion = new Date(d + (userTimeZoneOffset*60*60*1000));

exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
.timeZone('Turkey/Istanbul').onRun(async (context) => {
    var snapshot = await database.ref('Kullanicilar/{userId}/sistemdurumu').get();
    var oldDeger = snapshot.before.val();
    var newDeger = snapshot.after.val();
    
    if (newDeger > oldDeger){
      database.ref(`Kullanicilar/${Context.params.userId}/sistemdurumu1`).await().set(timeInRegion.getFullYear());
      database.ref(`Kullanicilar/${Context.params.userId}/sistemdurumu2`).await().set(timeInRegion.getMonth()+1);
      database.ref(`Kullanicilar/${Context.params.userId}/sistemdurumu3`).await().set(timeInRegion.getDate()); 
    }
  
    return null;
});
```

The error I get deploy.
can you help me with this.

i deploying functions

functions: Finished running predeploy script. i functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled... i functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled i functions: preparing functions directory for uploading... i functions: packaged functions (69.93 KB) for uploading i pubsub: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled... i scheduler: ensuring required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled...
scheduler: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
pubsub: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
functions: functions folder uploaded successfully i functions: updating Node.js 14 function scheduledFunctionCrontab(us-central1)...
functions[scheduledFunctionCrontab(us-central1)]: Successful update operation. i functions: cleaning up build files...
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions: scheduledFunctionCrontab(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run: firebase deploy --only "functions:scheduledFunctionCrontab"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run: firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

Comment: By "add await before each set statement" in your previous question I meant -> `await database.ref(\`Kullanicilar/${Context.params.userId}/sistemdurumu1\`).set(timeInRegion.getFullYear());` Try doing this for all 3 just like you've done on `var snapshot` line.

Comment: I think there is an issue with Firebase.
I used a sample timed function code from Firebase Documentation and got the same error                 exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
  return null;
});

Comment: Can you try `firebase deploy --only functions:scheduledFunctionCrontab --debug`  and share the output here?

Comment: ok i'm trying now

Comment: Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        scheduledFunctionCrontab(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:scheduledFunctionCrontab"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Comment: [2021-07-22T15:21:07.132Z]      Error during upsert schedule for projects/test-2d809/locations/us-central1/functions/scheduledFunctionCrontab: Cloud resource location is not set for this project but scheduled functions require it. Please see this documentation for more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations.

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help

Comment: Try going to https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/storage/ , selected the project and setup a bucket and select any location (which is suitable for you). Then retry deploying.

Comment: Error during upsert schedule for projects/test-2d809/locations/us-central1/functions/scheduledFunctionCrontab: Failed to create scheduler job projects/test-2d809/locations/europe-west1/ jobs/firebase-schedule-scheduledFunctionCrontab-us-central1: HTTP Error: 400, Schedule or time zone is invalid.

Comment: Could it be time zone related?

Comment: Yes, it should be `Asia/Istanbul` and not `Turkey/Istanbul` as per [TZ database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: I finally managed to deploy it :D but I'm not listening to the database :D .thanks  exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('*/1 * * * *')
.timeZone('Asia/Istanbul').onRun(async (context) => {

    
    console.log(' 1 dakika!');

    const snapshot = await database.ref('Kullanicilar/14876655/sistemdurumu').get();
   
    console.log(snapshot.val);
    
   
    return null;
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions),

> The value for timeZone must be a time zone name from the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Therefore the timezone should be `Asia/Istanbul` and not `Turkey/Istanbul`.

Apart from that, database update operations return a promise so you should use `await`. You can run them simultaneously in a `Promise.all()` if required.

```js
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
.timeZone('Asia/Istanbul').onRun(async (context) => {
           ^^^^
    var snapshot = await database.ref('Kullanicilar/{userId}/sistemdurumu').get();
    var oldDeger = snapshot.before.val();
    var newDeger = snapshot.after.val();
    
    if (newDeger > oldDeger){
      await database.ref(`Kullanicilar/${Context.params.userId}/sistemdurumu1`).set(timeInRegion.getFullYear());
      await database.ref(`Kullanicilar/${Context.params.userId}/sistemdurumu2`).set(timeInRegion.getMonth()+1);
      await database.ref(`Kullanicilar/${Context.params.userId}/sistemdurumu3`).set(timeInRegion.getDate()); 
    }
  
    return null;
});
```